Trigger the redraw of the cells without re-rendering the whole table
I am currently using Tabulator version 6.2.1. In our implementation, the contents of the cells can be influenced which should result a new 'redraw' of that particular cells (and potentially all cells that already were rendered) without having the scroll position reset to it's original position. What I am trying to ask is: Is there a way to tell tabulator to:

redraw / invalidate the cells that are currently visible and part of the virtual window that is not visible?
invalidate all already rendered cells (which would result in triggering the onRendered custom formatter again) to ensure they will get the new required state as well when they become visible.
all of this without getting the scroll position of the table reset to the first row (as this is very annoying in case of having a very long list of items).

There are several things I've tried:

Issue: Get hold of the "visible" rows instead of getting all rows. As you can imagine getting all rows and re-render these (performance wise) will have a huge impact in case the user has already scrolled down the whole list of items (in case of having a large list). Besides that: the visible rows do not contain the ones that are part of the virtual window. Additionally no re-render will be triggered on the cells that were already rendered, but not part of the virtual window. Additionally table.getRows does not include the child row items. This would mean I would need to iterate those to apply the re-render on these items.

Solution 1: Re-drawing the table (this has the disadvantage of the scroll position being reset).

Solution 2: Re-drawing the table re-applying the previous scroll position. In case the scroll position is still in the first virtual window.


The following piece of code does not give me the possibility to re-render the cells that were already rendered (and are part of the virtual window):
function changeBackgroundIssue() {
    const visibleRows = table.getRows( "visible" );
    visibleRows.forEach( ( row ) => {
        const backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor();
        const cell = row.getCell( "name" );
        const cellElement = d3.select( cell.getElement() );
        cellElement
            .style( "background-color", backgroundColor )
    } );
}

An example of this (and the other use-cases described above) can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nbg3mko6/
Please note that the give example exposes the problem in this small list already. But the use-case we have is a table that need to render 20.000K+ rows.
